# Powershell Extract and Rename as ZIP Filename

Tags: powershell, zip

Iv got an application that produces a ZIP file with a HTML document inside of it. However the extracted HTML file is not named the same as the zip file (for some strange reason that I have no control over).

I need to extract the zip file and rename the extracted file the same as the zip file name however I am unsure where this would slot in on my script some help would be appreciated please, script below:

```
#Files Location
$ZipFilesPath = "C:\Test\"
#Unzip To Same Location
$UnzipPath = "C:\Test\"

$Shell = New-Object -com Shell.Application
$Location = $Shell.NameSpace($UnzipPath)
$ZipFiles = Get-Childitem $ZipFilesPath -Recurse -Include *.ZIP
$FileCounter = 1

#Clear Initilisation Vars from Console
clear

foreach ($ZipFile in $ZipFiles) {
    #Get The Base Filename without the Filepath
    $ZipFileActualName = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($ZipFile.FullName)

    write-host "File: "  $ZipFileActualName

    $ZipFolder = $Shell.NameSpace($ZipFile.fullname)
    $Location.Copyhere($ZipFolder.items(), 1040)

    #Move Along to Next File
    $FileCounter++
}
```

Final Solution (With Added Piece From Nick Cox below)

```
#Location Of ZIP Files Defined Here
$ZipFilesPath = "C:\Test\";
#Unzip To Temp Folder Defined Here
$TempPath = "C:\Test\Temp"

#Create Our Temp File If It Doesnt Exist (Will Be Deleted Again)
If(!(test-path $TempPath))
{
      New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $TempPath
}

$Shell = New-Object -com Shell.Application
$Location = $Shell.NameSpace($TempPath)
$ZipFiles = Get-Childitem $ZipFilesPath -Recurse -Include *.ZIP
$FileCounter = 1

#Clear Initilisation Vars from Console
clear

foreach ($ZipFile in $ZipFiles) {
    #Get The Base Filename without the Filepath
    $ZipFileActualName = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($ZipFile.FullName)
    write-host "File: "  $ZipFileActualName
    $ZipFolder = $Shell.NameSpace($ZipFile.fullname)
    $Location.Copyhere($ZipFolder.items(), 1040)
    #Move Our Temp Files
    $HtmlFiles = Get-ChildItem $TempPath *.html
    $HtmlFiles |% {Move-Item  $_.Fullname "$UnzipPath/$ZipFileActualName.html"}
    #Move Along to Next File
    $FileCounter++
}

#Remove Our .ZIP Folders
Get-ChildItem -Path $ZipFilesPath -Include *.zip* -File -Recurse | foreach { $_.Delete()}

#Remove Our Temp Folder
Remove-Item –path $TempPath –recurse
```

Comment: To get the current name of the .html file you could [list zip file contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14204230/how-to-list-the-files-in-a-zip-in-powershell) and after expanding simply rename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not extract to a temp location and copy from there to the destination?

```
#Files Location
$ZipFilesPath = "C:\Test\"
#Unzip To Same Location
$UnzipPath = "C:\Test\"
$TempPath = "C:\Test\Temp"

$Shell = New-Object -com Shell.Application
$Location = $Shell.NameSpace($TempPath)
$ZipFiles = Get-Childitem $ZipFilesPath -Recurse -Include *.ZIP
$FileCounter = 1

#Clear Initialisation Vars from Console
clear

foreach ($ZipFile in $ZipFiles) {
    #Get The Base Filename without the Filepath
    $ZipFileActualName = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($ZipFile.FullName)

    write-host "File: "  $ZipFileActualName

    $ZipFolder = $Shell.NameSpace($ZipFile.fullname)
    $Location.Copyhere($ZipFolder.items(), 1040)

    $HtmlFiles = Get-ChildItem $TempPath *.html
    $HtmlFiles |% {Move-Item  $_.Fullname "$UnzipPath/$ZipFileActualName.html"}
    #Move Along to Next File
    $FileCounter++
}
```

By the way, if you're using PowerShell >= 5.0 you can unzip natively with [Expand-Archive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive?view=powershell-6).

Comment: Thank you for altering the script and placing in the piece of code for me. I have finished the script off and added the final solution that I am using to my original post. 

Additions include create a temp path if it didn't exist, deleting the temp folder after the function completes and then deleting all the ZIP folders out the main directory to keep it neat.

Answer (score 0):

First off, thank you everyone for your efforts with solving this ask.  I took the above code and modified it a bit to be more user friendly and repeatable.

```
<#
.Synopsis
Extract files from ZIP and rename files of the specified file extension to match the base name of the source ZIP file

.PARAMETER ZipFilesPath
Location of the ZIP files to extract

.PARAMETER FileExtension
File Extension of the extracted files to rename

.PARAMETER CleanUp
Remove the source ZIP files on completion, use with caution

.PARAMETER UnzipPath
Location to save the extracted and renamed files

.Notes

Name:       extract-zip.ps1
Author:     Steven French       
Version:    1.3
Changlog:

v0.1    Original base code from Soprono (https://stackoverflow.com/users/2657329/soprono) and Nick Cox (https://stackoverflow.com/users/56151/nick-cox): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50268035/powershell-extract-and-rename-as-zip-filename

v1.0    Initial Public Release

v1.1    Converted variables to parameters

v1.2    Switched to native PowerShell for the file extraction

v1.3    Verify a file with the same name doesn't already exist, if it does increment the file name using a counter until a unique name is found
        
.EXAMPLE
.\extract-zip.ps1 -ZipFilesPath "C:\Users\johnsmith\Videos" -FileExtension mp4 -CleanUp -UnzipPath c:\unzip

.EXAMPLE
.\extract-zip.ps1 -ZipFilesPath "C:\downloads\LinuxISOs" -FileExtension ISO 

#>

Param(  
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$ZipFilesPath,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$FileExtension,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)][switch]$CleanUp,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)][string]$UnzipPath = "$ZipFilesPath\Extracted"
)

#Unzip To Temp Folder Defined Here
$TempPath = "$ZipFilesPath\temp"

#Create Our Temp File If It Doesnt Exist (Will Be Deleted Again)
If (!(test-path $TempPath)) {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $TempPath
}

#Create Our Unzip Path If It Doesnt Exist
If (!(test-path $UnzipPath)) {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $UnzipPath
}

$ZipFiles = Get-Childitem $ZipFilesPath -Recurse -Include *.ZIP
$FileCounter = 1

#Clear Initilisation Vars from Console
Clear-Host

foreach ($ZipFile in $ZipFiles) {
    #Get The Base Filename without the Filepath
    $ISOFiles = $null
    $ZipFileActualName = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($ZipFile.FullName)
    Write-Host "File: "  $ZipFileActualName
    
    Expand-Archive -LiteralPath $ZipFile -DestinationPath $TempPath
    $ISOFiles = Get-ChildItem $TempPath *.$FileExtension
    $ISOFiles | ForEach-Object {
        Move-Item -Path $TempPath\*.$FileExtension -Destination $UnzipPath
        $fileName = "$UnzipPath/$ZipFileActualName.$FileExtension"

        # Check if the file exists
        if (Test-Path $fileName -PathType Leaf) {
            #Rename-Item -Path "$UnzipPath\$_" -NewName "$UnzipPath/$ZipFileActualName.$FileExtension"

            # Get the file extension
            $extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($fileName)

            # Remove the extension from the file name
            $baseName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($fileName)

            # Initialize a counter
            $counter = 1

            # Loop until a unique file name is found
            do {
                # Append the counter to the base name
                $newName = $baseName + $counter + $extension

                # Increment the counter
                $counter++
                #Test-Path $UnzipPath\$newName -PathType Leaf
            }
            until (-not (Test-Path $UnzipPath\$newName -PathType Leaf))

            # Rename the file
            Rename-Item -Path "$UnzipPath\$_" -NewName $newName

            # Display the new file name
            Write-Host "The file has been renamed to $newName"
        }
        else {
            # Display an error message
            Write-Host Error
        }
    }
             
}
    
#Move Along to Next File
$FileCounter++


if ($CleanUp) {
    #Remove Our .ZIP Folders
    Get-ChildItem -Path $ZipFilesPath -Include *.zip* -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object { $_.Delete() }
}

#Remove Our Temp Folder
Remove-Item -path $TempPath -recurse
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    foreach ($ZipFile in $ZipFiles) {
    #Get The Base Filename without the Filepath
    $ZipFileActualName = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($ZipFile.FullName)

    write-host "File: "  $ZipFileActualName

    $ZipFolder = $Shell.NameSpace($ZipFile.fullname)
    $Location.Copyhere($ZipFolder.items(), 1041)

    $HtmlFiles = Get-ChildItem $TempPath *.html
    $HtmlFiles |% {Move-Item  $_.Fullname "$UnzipPath/$ZipFileActualName.html"}
    #Move Along to Next File
    $FileCounter++
}
```