# Get folder name in zip file with Powershell

Tags: powershell, zip

I have a zip file with this content structure

```
zipfile.zip
  - mainfolder
    - file1
    - file2
    - subfolder
```

I need to determine the name of "mainfolder", how can I get the name of "mainfolder" using powershell? I tried different things, nothing worked, I'm a total beginner in powershell. I'm using Powershell V2.0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list the files in a zip in powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14204230/how-to-list-the-files-in-a-zip-in-powershell)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the .NET namespace `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` to read the zip via the `ZipFile` class, however it only returns file entries so you'd need to infer the file name from the first entry as follows, which might be a bit fragile:

```
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.IO.Compression.FileSystem')

$zipFile = 'zipfile.zip'
$Files = [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($zipFile).Entries

(($Files | Where FullName -match '/' | Select -First 1).Fullname -Split '/')[0]
```

Comment: There might be entries first without `/` (even if OPs sample doesn't show this). So `(($Files | Where FullName -match '/' | Select -First 1).Fullname -Split '/')[0]` should be more secure.

Comment: @Lemming If answers solve your question or you find them helpful you should consider to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and/or [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)