# Powershell read folder name and count file in a zip file

Tags: powershell, zip

I'm newbie on powershell. I have a zip file with the following structure:
file.zip

Folder1

Folder11 that contains 10 files

Folder12 that contains 5 files

Folder2

Folder 21 that contains 7 files

log.txt

My goal is to have the following result:
-Folder1 contains 15 files
-Folder2 contains 7 files

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Start by looking [how to list zip contents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14204577/503046)

Answer (score 0):

This code does not read directly from the .zip file. From what I can tell, doing that will take a bit more work. Instead, it extracts the contents of the archive to a temporary directory, recursively gets the folders and number of items in each, then deletes the temporary directory.

```
Add-Type -Assembly "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem"

$zipFile = "path-to-zip-file"
$outPath = "path-to-temp-dir"
$hash = @{}

[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($zipFile, $outPath)

Get-ChildItem -Path $outPath -Recurse -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    $hash.Add($_.FullName,((Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName | Measure-Object).Count))
}

Write-Host $hash

Remove-Item $outPath -Recurse
```

Comment: Hi D-squared if I've understood is not possible to uncompress the archive because we're talking about a file with size > 250GB. So the request is to do what mentioned above without extracting the entire content in a temp directory. Thanks in advance.